# Store a byte array

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

The following is a sinatra route:

```
post '/accounts/:id/video' do |acc_id|
  acc_id = params[:id].to_s
  user = db_find('thrill.users',{_id: acc_id})
  if user
   db_update('thrill.users', { _id: acc_id},
      { '$set' => 
        { video: request.body.to_s }})
    res(200, :sys_message => 'Video stored.')
  else
    res(201, :sys_message => "User not found")
  end
end
```

It gets a response from the client with a video file in the form of a byte array. If I store it directly in the database, it is stored in the following format:

```
PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x007f48f8485b50
```

This has to be stored in the database in a format that can be retrieved later and sent back to the client. How can I read the byte array? The preferred format for storing would be in a form of a url which the client can access and stream the video. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Rack specification](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC), about the request body (which is what `request.body` is:

> The input stream is an IO-like object which contains the raw HTTP POST data. When applicable, its external encoding must be “ASCII-8BIT” and it must be opened in binary mode, for Ruby 1.9 compatibility. The input stream must respond to gets, each, read and rewind.

The [`PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput` class](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/release-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb#L73) meets these requirements. Calling `to_s` on an instance of this calls will just give the Ruby string representation of the object. To get the *contents* you need to call `read`, e.g.

```
{ video: request.body.read }
```

This will read the entire body into a string which you can then pass to Mongo.

Comment: Thanks for this, it moved a little further but now I got this error **BSON::InvalidStringEncoding - String not valid UTF**   while uploading a  5mb video

Comment: This is how I changed my code     
             `{ video: request.body.read }})`

Comment: @gautam that sounds like a different problem — you should ask another question. It looks like an issue with Mongo/BSON and I don’t know much about those but someone else might.

Comment: Thanks a lot but tell me one thing  I just changed what you told, I hope that isn't giving this  error?

Comment: @gautam no, this change is unrelated to BSON. This is just getting the data from the client into your server, the new error seems to be getting it from there into Mongo.